# jquery and php: need to optimize images on uploads

Tags: php, jquery, image, optimization

I was wondering if anyone can teach me how to optimize an image when a user uploads? I would like to reduce the size quality of the image so when I show it on my page, it will load faster.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php, examples are very easy to follow.

Added: I recomend you to keep the source image in its original size and create the resized one in a different folder.

Added: According to documentation, the function `imagecopyresampled` used by the class, does some kind of optimization:

_***imagecopyresampled()** copies a rectangular portion of one image to another image, smoothly interpolating pixel values so that, in particular, reducing the size of an image still retains a great deal of clarity. _*

Anyway, if you want more fine tune, as @mingos said, you can use ImageMagick, it's a bit harder, but there is a lot of samples here: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/

Comment: This example only shows resizing? It doesn't show how to optimize the image quality?

Comment: Link above changed: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

Answer (score 2):

Use GD or ImageMagick:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: Do you have any examples? I'm new to php and working with an examples helps me better understand, thank you

Comment: You can google for them, there are tons of examples out there.

Comment: IMagick can't be more readable and self explanatory o_O. What is exactly that you don't understand about it?

Comment: it says i must install something? "PECL"? so if i install this, imagick should works? This would be on localhost. But what if I must do it on a host site? do I have to install "PECL" too? sorry i'm total n00b

Comment: PECL is a library of extensions. Imagick is one of the extensions available in PECL. Just install Imagick. If you don't want to install anthing, stick with GD2. It's more primitive than Imagick, but it comes with PHP out of the box.